# SQL Select tables / list tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to ask for help.

As I have 500 plus tables, and I need to search those table's column having some similar words. Is it possible to search and list those tables?

E.g

Table 1 - Name, age, height

Table 2 - Result, Name, Score

Table 3 - Name, Pic, Parent1, Parent2

I wan to do a query to select all the table that any of the column contain the word "%Name%", is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Just run following query in your db and replace your search string with string and it will work.

### SQL for find particular word/value from all columns and tables in a database

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @valueToFind VARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @columnName VARCHAR(1000)

SET @valueToFind = 'string' 
SET @columnName = '%%' 

CREATE TABLE #TMP 
   (Clmn VARCHAR(500), 
   CNT INT) 

SELECT @SQL=COALESCE(@SQL,'')+CAST('INSERT INTO #TMP Select ''' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME + '.' + COLUMN_NAME + ''' AS Clmn, count(*) CNT FROM '  
        + TABLE_SCHEMA + '.[' + TABLE_NAME + 
       '] WHERE [' + COLUMN_NAME + '] LIKE ''%' + @valueToFind + '%'' ;'  AS VARCHAR(8000)) 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  
   JOIN sysobjects B  
   ON INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME = B.NAME 
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE @columnName AND xtype = 'U' 
   AND DATA_TYPE IN ('char','nchar','ntext','nvarchar','text','varchar') 

--PRINT (@SQL) 

EXEC(@SQL) 

SELECT * FROM #TMP WHERE CNT > 0 
DROP TABLE #TMP
```

### -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------